# Integrating a single file that was renamed in a source stream to the target stream

Tags: perforce, perforce-integrate, perforce-stream, perforce-branch-spec

I have two streams, `Source` and `Target`. A file was at some point created on `Source`, called `FileA`. Then, Target stream was created branching from `Source`. `FileA` on `Source` was then renamed to `FileB`.

Now I need to merge this change into `Target`. The result should be `FileA` on `Target` being renamed to `FileB`.

I can generally merge a single file using `p4 integrate` and specifying `fromFiles` and `toFiles`.

This workflow breaks for files marked with `move/delete`. I get an error message that says the following:

```
move/delete(s) must be integrated along with matching move/add(s)
```

Okay then, I'll see what the `move/add` target was and add that to the command. But here's the twist. `p4 integrate` allows targeting multiple files only by using their filespec system. I cannot specify two separate files, unless they share some part of the path, which doesn't always have to be the case in the situation above.

But not all hope is lost yet, since, instead of specifying `fromFiles` and `toFiles` in the `p4 integrate` explicitly, you can use `branch mapping` instead. There you can specify any number of mappings, so I can explicitly add both the `move/delete` pair and `move/add` pair. Problem solved, right?

No, because, that also doesn't work because perforce seems to process the `branch mapping` line by line, so the as soon as it reaches the first line, it throws the same error. Even if I swap the ordering, putting `move/add` pair before `move/delete` pair, it still complains.

Is it really impossible to integrate a single rename from one stream to the other if the files are renamed to something completely different? How do I handle this?

Comment: It would be helpful to see the exact commands you ran -- some of what you describe doesn't agree with my understanding of how the integrate logic works, but without seeing the actual commands and their output it's hard to guess the reason for the discrepancy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases you can actually just integrate the move/add; as long as the original branch mapping is simple enough (and for streams it usually is), the corresponding move/delete will be discovered automatically.  Specifying the full branch mapping is only strictly needed if it's something tricky (like if individual paths in the source are mapped to different paths in the target and the file was moved between those paths).

Here's the error trying to merge `FileA` on its own:

```
C:\Perforce\karl>p4 merge --from Source FileA
Move/delete(s) must be integrated along with matching move/add(s).
```

and here we are just merging `FileB` on its own:

```
C:\Perforce\karl>p4 merge --from Source FileB
//stream/Target/FileA#1 - integrate from //stream/Source/FileB#1 (remapped from //stream/Target/FileB)
... must resolve content from //stream/Source/FileB#1
... must resolve move to //stream/Target/FileB
```

Note that when we said we wanted to merge `FileB`, p4 was able to figure out that it's linked to `FileA`, and so we open `FileA` for integrate while scheduling a filename resolve.  Then we resolve:

```
C:\Perforce\karl>p4 resolve
c:\Perforce\karl\FileA - merging //stream/Source/FileB#1
Diff chunks: 0 yours + 0 theirs + 0 both + 0 conflicting
Accept(a) Edit(e) Diff(d) Merge (m) Skip(s) Help(?) at: a
//bob-dvcs-1709920089/FileA - copy from //stream/Source/FileB
c:\Perforce\karl\FileA - resolving move to //stream/Target/FileB
Filename resolve:
at: //stream/Target/FileB
ay: //stream/Target/FileA
Accept(a) Skip(s) Help(?) at: a
//stream/Target/FileB - moved from //stream/Target/FileA
```

(I could also have just done `p4 resolve -as` here to do it automatically, but then we wouldn't get the preview of the individual resolve actions.)

Now the file is open for move in the `Target` stream:

```
C:\Perforce\karl>p4 opened
//stream/Target/FileA#1 - move/delete default change (text)
//stream/Target/FileB#1 - move/add default change (text)

C:\Perforce\karl>p4 resolved
c:\Perforce\karl\FileB - copy from //stream/Source/FileB#1
c:\Perforce\karl\FileB - moved from //stream/Target/FileA#1
c:\Perforce\karl\FileB - resolved move (copy from //stream/Target/FileB)
```

Another option would have been to merge by changelist (assuming that there wasn't a bunch of other stuff in that changelist that we specifically wanted to avoid):

```
C:\Perforce\karl>p4 revert //...
//stream/Target/FileA#1 - was move/delete, reverted
//stream/Target/FileB#none - was move/add, deleted

C:\Perforce\karl>p4 filelog //stream/Source/fileB
//stream/Source/FileB
... #1 change 4 move/add on 2024/03/08 by bob@bob-dvcs-1709920089 (text) 'moveB'
... ... moved from //stream/Source/FileA#1
//stream/Source/FileA
... #1 change 2 add on 2024/03/08 by bob@bob-dvcs-1709920089 (text) 'addA'
... ... moved into //stream/Source/FileB#1
... ... branch into //stream/Target/FileA#1

C:\Perforce\karl>p4 merge --from Source @4,4
//stream/Target/FileA#1 - integrate from //stream/Source/FileB#1 (remapped from //stream/Target/FileB)
... must resolve content from //stream/Source/FileB#1
... must resolve move to //stream/Target/FileB
```

Changelist 4 will of course include both the move/delete and move/add (because moves are guaranteed to be atomic), so that's another way to make sure that you're selecting both revisions.  If there were other edits made to the file, either before or after the move, integrating by changelist ("cherry-picking" the changelist) will specifically avoid merging those edits.

Comment: The merge command actually did the trick, thanks!